# Can anyone explain how this summation was simplified/rearranged? I can't for the life of me follow the steps

Tags: probability, summation

See attached image. Part of a question asking to calculate the marginal pmf when the joint pmf is known.

[image: Marginal probability mass function]

Comment: How far can you get?  Which step do you not understand?

Comment: The only thing I could think to take outside the summation was the e^(-lambda). How did the first summation become rearranged the second?

Comment: I don't understand what $\sum$ means.  Could you _write out explicitly_ (as in $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots $) what the first three or four terms in the expressions on the right are?

Comment: Write out the binomial coefficient: $z!$ cancels in numerator and denominator.  Also note that they have multiplied and divided by $\lambda^y$  Note that $y$ is constant, so you can pull out $p^y$ for example.

Comment: Ohh that makes a lot more sense forgot to write out the binomial coefficient now it all rearranges correctly thanks

Comment: How does the fraction in the top right after the summation sign become e^(lambda(1-p)) ?

Answer (score 0):

$P(Y=y)=\sum_{z=y}^\infty\binom{z}{y}p^y(1-p)^{z-y}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda ^z}{z!}$.We have $
\binom{z}{y}=\frac{z!}{y!(z-y)!}$ and $\lambda^z=\lambda^y\lambda^{z-y}$ givimg second term.
Let $k=z-y$ so the second term sum becomes $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^k}{k!}=e^{\lambda(1-p)}$ giving the third term.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one the summand goes like this$$\binom{z}{y}p^y(1-p)^{z-y}{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^z\over z!}{={z!\over y!(z-y!)}p^y(1-p)^{z-y}{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^z\over z!}\\={1\over y!(z-y!)}p^y(1-p)^{z-y}{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^z\over 1}\\={e^{-\lambda}(p\lambda)^y\over y!}{(1-p)^{z-y}\lambda^{z-y}\over(z-y)!}}$$after all, substitute $u=z-y$ and conclude.